# Using a conditional statement IF to control whether a row is added or not

Tags: database, postgresql, if-statement

I'm currently learning how to use databases through PostgreSQL. I'm defining a function that will add rows from one table to another based on various conditions, one condition is that if the row already exists in the target table, it won't be added but no exception will be raised, the program will simply continue onto the next row. As you may have guessed all of this is taking place within `LOOP...END LOOP`; of a `FOR`.

The problem is that our professor considers `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` non-standard and insists we use another method. I have searched extensively but really don't understand how to apply some answers people have suggested in similar cases. My idea was indeed:

```
IF variable1, variable2, variable3 NOT IN (SELECT v1, v2, v3 FROM target_table) THEN INSERT INTO target_table VALUES(variable1, variable2, variable3);
END IF;
```

But that is obviously not correct from a syntax point of view. Can anybody give me some guidance?

Thanks

Comment: You say "I have searched extensively but really don't understand how to apply some answers people have suggested in similar cases"; it would be better if you link or tell those suggestions, to discuss them more thoroughly. That would help people to get into the real problem and concrete things, because the description is a bit vague and long

Comment: That is a good idea Carlos, it's the first time I've asked a question about databases on her, I didn't even consider it. Gary's answer has given me what I need bt I'll keep it in mind for my next question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (v1,v2,v3)
SELECT
    variable1,
    variable2,
    variable3
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM target_table 
    WHERE v1 = variable1 and v2 = variable2 and v3 = variable3)
```

However there are some caveats.

If one of your variables is nullable you can't just use "=".   You need to do something like:

```
(v1 = variable1 OR (v1 is null and variable1 is null))
```

and it gets bulky pretty quickly and can be slow on large tables as it can prevent indices from being used.

You also need to worry about the concurrency aspects.  If you're issuing this statement where there are concurrent inserts/updates to the table you'll need to consider when rows become visible as rows may get inserted between the select and the insert.

Check out the transaction isolation settings in PostgreSQL for these details.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/transaction-iso.html